# Shifting array elements +1

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

i Have created array for 6 element i want to add new element at 0 index and want to shift all +1 so how i can do this in for loop or any easy way to perform for big arrays

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    main(){
        int shift;
        int shift2;
        int shift3;
        int shift4;
        int shift5;

        int array[6]={1,2,3,4,5};
        shift=array[0];
        shift2=array[1];
        shift3=array[2];
        shift4=array[3];
        shift5=array[4];

            array[1]=shift ;
                array[2]=shift2;
                    array[3]=shift3 ;
                        array[4]=shift4 ;
                            array[5]=shift5 ;

            array[0]=90;

            for(int i=0 ; i< 6; i++){


            cout<<"array value at index "<<i<<" is "<<array[i]<<endl;


        }




    }
```

Comment: A splendid program!

Comment: You want to add new elements to your array? Probably you want to use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: That's not valid C++. `main` has return type `int`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

Comment: You only need 1 temporary.

Comment: i used temporary  but it changes all to 1

Comment: You could [std::rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) and then overwrite the first element

Answer (score 1):

First, you should shift all array items from the last one. After that just overwrite first array item with index 0

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 6;
    int array[ARRAY_SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0};
    for(int idx = ARRAY_SIZE - 1; idx > 0; --idx)
    {
        array[idx] = array[idx - 1];
    }
    array[0] = 10;

    for(int idx = 0; idx < ARRAY_SIZE; ++idx)
    {
       std::cout << "Array value at index " << idx << " is " << array[idx] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array value at index 0 is 10
Array value at index 1 is 1
Array value at index 2 is 2
Array value at index 3 is 3
Array value at index 4 is 4
Array value at index 5 is 5
```

Answer (score 0):

if you read up on memmove and memcpy the difference may give you the clue why using 1 temporary didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could [std::rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) and then overwrite the first element

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int array[6] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::rotate(std::begin(array), std::prev(std::end(array)), std::end(array));
    array[0] = 90;
    for (const auto &el: array) {
        std::cout << el << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
90
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do the task for an array of integers is to use the standard C function `memmove`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array );

    std::memmove( array + 1, array, ( N - 1 ) * sizeof( int ) );

    array[0] = 90;

    for ( const auto &item : array ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
90 1 2 3 4
```

Another approaches is to use standard algorithms as for example  `std::rotate`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array );

    std::rotate( std::begin( array ), std::prev( std::end( array ) ),
                        std::end( array ) );

    array[0] = 90;

    for ( const auto &item : array ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
90 1 2 3 4
```

If to use a for loop then it can look the following way using the standard function `std::exchange`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array );

    int tmp = 90;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        tmp = std::exchange( array[i], tmp );
    }

    for ( const auto &item : array ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Again the program output is

```
90 1 2 3 4
```

Without using any standard function the program can look like

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array );

    for ( size_t i = N; i-- > 1;  )
    {
        array[i] = array[i-1];
    }

    array[0] = 90;

    for ( const auto &item : array ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

And again the program output is

```
90 1 2 3 4
```